# NativeScript Sidekick Errors while Generate Provisioning Profile and Certificate

Tags: ios, nativescript, sidekick

I am trying to setup a Mobile development environment, a true WORA.
NativeScript seems to be ticking all the boxes. 
I have therefore installed Visual Studio Code with NativeScript Plugin and SideKick. I am trying to do a simple thing at the moment, namely testing HelloWorld App on physical devices such as Android Tablet/Phone and iPad. Android was a breeze however iPad proved to be a pain. I am trying to use "iOS Auto Generate Provisioning Profile and Certificate" inside SideKick but I am getting two types of errors:

1) Using my Main Apple ID (with no Developer account) I am getting following message:

An error has occured while generating the certificate and mobile provision. Reason: Two-step verification not supported at the moment

Fair enough, I thought I will try a Free Apple ID (as advised in SideKick documentation, see result in next bullet point)

2) Free (newly created) Apple ID

An error has occured while generating the certificate and mobile provision. Reason: Could not find app with bundle id. (node:12659) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated. Could not find app with bundle id

Is there any step-by-step walk through on how to test simple apps on your local Apple devices?!?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Whats your bundle id, for free account it must be really unique. Try to run the complied project form Xcode itself, that might give you some better error log.

Comment: Yup, that was the issue. I have used some random number at the end of my Application ID and it worked like a charm. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for updating. I have added same as an answer below. So it is easy for others to notice, if possible I would ask you to mark that as solution.

Comment: I have managed to generate Provisioning Profile and Certificate and saved those details in my iOS build config. When I try to build my Project however I get a vague error "Your system is not configured for local builds" with no additional details. Any idea what it might mean?!?

Comment: Have you installed all the prerequisites for iOS listed here - https://docs.nativescript.org/start/ns-setup-os-x#system-requirements

Comment: Nope, turned out I got it all wrong. I did not realise that process of building native App will require either macOS or Cloud build. I naively thought this could all be done by my winOS installation of NS/Sidekick.

Managed to use Cloud Build for now, will need to dust off my MacBook at some point :)

What would be the best setup for dev using that framework? Some centralised repository for your code (GitHub), IDE setup on each platform (winOS and macOS) to be able to build and debug Native App?!? In case if we need to debug a NS layer though... is there an IDE that supports both?!?

Comment: Apart form the prerequisites, everything else are upto you. You may choose any IDE of your choice, though most people use VS Code which has a extension for debugging. Webstorm too has a plugin for NativeScript. The framework also offers option to debug with Chrome developer tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue could be the bundle id, for a free account the bundle id must be really **unique**, across anyone ever used so far.